# Relating the norm of a diffeomorphism to the distance in a Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, diffeomorphism, mean-value-theorem

Suppose $M$ is a Riemannian manifold and $f: M \to M$ is a diffeo.
I wonder whether or not there are ways to relate the operator norm of $df$ to the distances $d(x,y)$ and $d(f(x), f(y))$, like the mean value inequality does for applications $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$, for instance.

I know, for example, that if $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$, then there is an analogue to the classical MVT that states that $$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |df_p||x-y|,$$ where $p$ is a point in the geodesic joining $x$ to $y$ maximazing the norm of $df$. Is there anything similar in the case the range is not $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Just checking that you've read and thought about the answer I posted. Do you have any follow-up questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that $M$ is complete. Choose a geodesic $\gamma$ from $x$ to $y$ so that the length of $\gamma$ is $\ell(\gamma)=d(x,y)=L$. Then
\begin{align*}
d(f(x),f(y)) &\le \ell(f\circ\gamma) = \int_0^L \|(f\circ\gamma)'(t)\|dt =
\int_0^L \|df_{\gamma(t)}(\gamma'(t))\|dt\\ &\le \max_{t\in [0,L]}\|df_{\gamma(t)}\|L =\max_{t\in [0,L]}\|df_{\gamma(t)}\|d(x,y).
\end{align*}

I'll leave it to you to modify this slightly in the case the metric is not complete.

**COMMENT**: The hypothesis that $f$ is a diffeomorphism is only relevant if you want to get a double inequality.

Comment: In the case of a diffeomorphism the distance would be bounded bellow by a term involving the norm of the inverse, right?

Comment: Right. But you can use the inverse function theorem to relate that to the norm of the map itself.

Comment: I'm, sorry, but I'm still having a little trouble with the second inequality. When I try do what you suggest, I get a lower bound envolving the minimum of one over the norm of the inverse. I know, from the IFT, that this quantity is bounded above the norm of the original diffeo, but how can use this to get rid of the inverse in the double inequality?

Comment: I can’t follow what you’re saying. Please edit your question to include the actual mathematics.

Comment: I wasn't aware LaTex worked in the comment section, sorry. Well, since $(x,y) = (f^{-1}(f(x)),f^{-1}(f(y)))$, using the inequallity you proved, we obtain $\min  \|df^{-1} \|^{-1}d(x,y) \le d(f(x),f(y))$. On the other hand, since the operator norm is submultiplicative the IFT implies  $\|df^{-1} \|^{-1} \le \|df\|.$ How can these facts be used to get a double inequality only in terms of $\|df\|$, without the inverse?

Comment: Have you applied the Inverse Function Theorem? $df^{-1}_{f(p)}=(df_p)^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, but then $1 = \|\mathrm{id}\| = \| df^{-1}_{f(p)} \circ df_p\| \le \| df^{-1}_{f(p)}\| \|df_p\|$, because in general the operator norm is only submultiplicative, right? This means $\| df^{-1}_{f(p)}\| ^{-1}$ is not exactly equal to $\|df_p\|,$ but only bounded above by it, so it is not clear to me how to rewrite the inequality $\min\| df^{-1}\|d(x,y) \leq d(f(x), f(y)$ in terms of $\|df\|$ alone. Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Oh, right. You need control of the norm of the inverse of $df$ along the path. This is not surprising, since you can’t determine $\|A^{-1}\|$ from $\|A\|$. (In the diagonalizable case, you need largest eigenvalue and smallest eigenvalue.) My point was that it boils down to just $df$ along the path.